# How do I stop reactjs from re-rendering the page when the user tabs out?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

Very general question: I have a relatively simple react/nextjs page with a graph interface on it. Every time I change tab on Firefox and revisit the page, the page will re-render and cause the interface to reset. How can I stop this? I have tried using memos on the relevant components but to no avail.

Edit with some code snippets, some variable names have been censored:

This is a memo containing a switch which returns the contents based on the variable 't'.

```
const PageContents = memo(function PageContents({t}) {
    console.log("re-rendering the page contents...")
    switch(t) {
    case "graph":
        console.log("graph tab")
        return(
        <>
        <Graph data={data}/>   
        </>
        )
    ...other cases...
});
```

Return:

```
return (
<>
    <Helmet>
         <title>Title</title>
    </Helmet>
    <MenuAppBar position="absolute"/>
    <Container component="main" maxWidth={false} >
    <Stack direction={"row"} justifyContent={"space-between"}>
        <Box pt={3} display={"flex"}>
            <Typography variant="h4">
            Schema: {schema}
            </Typography>
        </Box>
        <TabBar/>
    </Stack>
    <BasicBreadcrumbs/>
    <PageContents t={tab}/> //'tab' comes from router.query
    </Container>
</>
)
```

Comment: Please share some related code to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: Idealy switching tabs should not rerender the UI components, so try to share some useful code that may be causing this

Comment: @Kamran Thank you, I was wondering if this was an intended feature. I've updated the question with some code snippets. However, I also deleted the vestigial useState()'s that were cluttering the top of the document, and that seems to have fixed the problem. Do you know of any reasons why a useState() would cause this behaviour?

Comment: I can't think of any React reasons this would be happening, however some browsers will kill off background tabs processes if they are left idle long enough, or if the system is running low on memory. If that's the case, there's not much you can do.

Comment: @BrenD A sample codesandbox would help in answering this question better. Thanks!

Comment: can you share that removed usestate piece of code?

Comment: It was really just const [x,y] = useState([]) repeated a few times. I had put it there before moving those variables into a child element. They weren't referenced anywhere, only initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing all the unused useState()s at the top of the component.